# Deleted record not removed from lookup

Tags: lookup

Record A has a lookup to Record B. Record B is deleted. For some reason, the lookup on Record A isn't cleared. When I click the link to the lookup in the SF ui, it brings me to a "record deleted" page

is this an issue with the recycle bin or something?

Comment: Is your lookup field set to "clear the value when the related record is deleted"?

Comment: How are you navigating to Record A after deleting Record B? Is this in Lightning? If you do a browser refresh of Record A's page, does the lookup still appear to be populated?

Comment: @DerekF yeah, clear the value of the field is on

Comment: @ThomasTaylor in classic but I'm refreshing the page and still see it. See it when I query the db too

Answer (score 0):

I have an example where the lookup field is not visible in the Lightning record detail, and the same record shows the linked record id in Classic, even though the related record was deleted.  Please see the images below of the same record after the related record was deleted.

[image: Cleared lookup field in Classic]

[image: Cleared lookup field in Lightning]

From this [other post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220972/deleted-contacts-id-is-not-removed-from-converted-lead-why), it seems that a value still existing in the db is expected behavior, if there's no other trigger/automation that explicitly deletes the value from the lookup field.