# Why lookup reference Ids not cleared on deletion?

Tags: opportunity, quote, sync, sales

If I delete the quote record "Synced Quote" field on opportunity does not clear the value. Because of this any further update on Opportunity fails with "Invalid Cross Reference Id" exception.
At Opportunity record the quote reference is present even though record doesn't exist.

For what reasons salesforce doesn't clear look up references if looked up record is deleted? Is this bug?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be considered a bug, I would expect the reference to be removed as well.
However, the "deleted" record is not actually gone yet, it is only marked as deleted. Only after clearing the Recycle Bin the record is really gone. At that point the reference should finally be removed.

Comment: Actually, It doesn't go even I clear the bin. That's pain point considering all the further updates on the record willl throw exception that invalid reference id. Only way was to manually blank them.

Comment: @sfdcfox Sorry to bother but if you can put your view.

Comment: We've had a similar issue with converted leads still linking to deleted contacts (see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220972/deleted-contacts-id-is-not-removed-from-converted-lead-why). According to SF support this "works as designed" (see comments in above question).